# Open a file with unicode path

Tags: c++, boost, unicode

I'm working under windows 7 with mingw. I have encountered some weird behaviour with unicode filenames. My program needs to be portable, and I'm using `boost::filesystem (v 1.53)` to handle the file paths.

This has all been going well, until I needed to open files with unicode filenames. 
This is not about the content of the file, but the file's name.

I tried the following: For testing I made a folder named `C:\UnicodeTest\вячеслав` and I tried creating a file inside of it, by appending the file name `test.txt` to the boost wpath.
For some reason the creation of the file fails. I'm using boost's `fstream`s and when I try to open the file, the failbit of the stream is set. 
Now the funny thing is, that when I append a foldername to the path instead, a call to `create_directories()` succeeds and creates the correct directory `C:\UnicodeTest\вячеслав\folder`.

I really don't understand why it won't work with a file. This is the code I use:

```
boost::filesystem::wpath path;

// find the folder to test
boost::filesystem::wpath dirPath = "C:\\UnicodeTest";
vector<boost::filesystem::wpath> files;
copy(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(dirPath), boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(), back_inserter(files));

for(boost::filesystem::wpath &file : files)
{
    if(boost::filesystem::is_directory(file))
    {
        path = file;
        break;
    }
}

// create a path for the folder
boost::filesystem::wpath folderPath = path / "folder";
// this works just fine
boost::filesystem::create_directories(folderPath);

// create a path for the file
boost::filesystem::wpath filePath = path / "test.txt";

boost::filesystem::ofstream stream;

// this fails
stream.open(filePath);

if(!stream)
{
    cout << "failed to open file " << path << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "success" << endl;
}
```

Comment: While not directly related to your question, http://utf8everywhere.org has an extensive discussion on how to do things properly on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the issue correctly, the issue of being unable to create a file directly within `C:\UnicodeTest\вячеслав` occurs when you do not create the `folder` directory, as illustrated below.

```
// create a path for the folder
//boost::filesystem::wpath folderPath = path / "folder";
// this works just fine
//boost::filesystem::create_directories(folderPath);

// create a path for the file
boost::filesystem::wpath filePath = path / "test.txt";
```

I was able to get this to work by making the filename a wchar_t string:

```
// create a path for the file
boost::filesystem::wpath filePath = path / L"test.txt";
```

Comment: It doesn't matter whether I create the other folder or not - I still can't create the file. The folder was more or less the proof that the original path was correct. Making the filename a wchar_t string doesn't change anything, either.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Win7 plus boost 1.52,  so not exactly your configuration. However, when `boost::filesystem::wpath filePath = path / "test.txt";` was used, it ignored the filename and did not append it to path. But when I used `L"test.txt"` it did append the filename to the path and allowed the file to be created once it was written to.

Comment: If you can't get this to work, it would be worthwhile asking this question at the boost user newsgroup at news://news.gmane.org:119/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user

Comment: Here, it will always append the filename, but it won't create nor write to the file.

Comment: Assuming that stream opens, after `stream.open(filePath)`, which it does for me, did you try something like `stream << "test";` to write characters to the stream and `stream.close()` to write the stream?

Comment: Yes I tried that, too. No success. The really weird part is, creating directories works just fine.